# Holt-Winters Timeseries forecasting with statsmodels

Tags: time-series, prediction, holtwinters

I just following a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785479/holt-winters-time-series-forecasting-with-statsmodels) to tryout my first prediction with the sample dataset below.  I was expecting a prediction graph like [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ialsm.jpg), but I got the graph like the attached here.[got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npnYR.png)

my sample code is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', 
        parse_dates=['date'], 
        index_col='date')

df.index.freq = 'H'

train, test = df.iloc[:250, 0], df.iloc[250:, 0]
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train, seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=12).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1])

plt.plot(train.index, train, label='Train')
plt.plot(test.index, test, label='Test')
plt.plot(pred.index, pred, label='Holt-Winters')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

my sample data set which re-sampled by hourly

```
date,count
2018-08-19 18:00,11
2018-08-19 19:00,4412
2018-08-19 20:00,4300
2018-08-19 21:00,3522
2018-08-19 22:00,2579
2018-08-19 23:00,1546
2018-08-20 00:00,918
2018-08-20 01:00,492
2018-08-20 02:00,299
2018-08-20 03:00,184
2018-08-20 04:00,201
2018-08-20 05:00,334
2018-08-20 06:00,867
2018-08-20 07:00,1767
2018-08-20 08:00,2904
2018-08-20 09:00,3892
2018-08-20 10:00,4744
2018-08-20 11:00,5081
2018-08-20 12:00,5370
2018-08-20 13:00,5408
2018-08-20 14:00,5523
2018-08-20 15:00,5162
2018-08-20 16:00,5182
2018-08-20 17:00,4685
2018-08-20 18:00,4472
2018-08-20 19:00,4454
2018-08-20 20:00,4406
2018-08-20 21:00,3719
2018-08-20 22:00,2636
```

What am I missing?

**[Edit]**

After I changed seasonal_periods from 12 to 24, I got this graph.

[After changed to 24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riQob.png)

**[Edit]**

[After removed Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYa9s.png)

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, you seem to have the wrong seasonality cycle.

Try seasonal_periods=24, instead of seasonal_periods=12.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did change the seasonal_periods from 12 to 24 and now I got this graph, Please see the Edit section for the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your new fit may be correct : the exceptional values of week 8 may very well lead to an overestimation of the seasonal factors.

Make a test: remove those week (divide them by 4) and make a tentative fit. If the fit is better, you can start to fit a better value than an eyestimate.

If the fit does not change, then the overestimation may come from the smoothing_level, the smoothing_seasonal, or other parameters of the [fit](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.fit.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.fit).

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I have removed those data from my data set, Now graphs looks good and aligned with my train data, However it's not predicting, means I don't see the graph after 9/19. How do I got that in the graph. Attached the recent graph after removing those few days of data.