# How can I import the R ets() function in Python

Tags: python, holtwinters

I would like to estimate parameters for Holt-Winters exponential smoothing. I saw that R offers ets() function that estimates the model parameters. I work with python in Jupyter notebook. I need to know if there is a way to import this function from R.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561258/r-python-install-packages-on-rpy2 may help

Comment: I have tried but I have a problem installing rpy2 in the first place. I see that one user solved it with environment variables but I am not that experienced to know what he means, without seeing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Holt-Winters time series forecasting with statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785479/holt-winters-time-series-forecasting-with-statsmodels)

Comment: @AkselA It is not working for me for two reasons. I need to estimate the best parameters. But even if I decide to hard code it, I still get an error because of this line: pred = hw_model.predict(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1]). The error: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

Comment: @Yana: I suggest you ask a question about how to solve that then. I'm I afraid I can't help you with Python code.

Comment: @AkselA Thank you. I will check some other options too.

Comment: `ExponentialSmoothing` should optimize the parameters for you by default. Have you worked through an example like the one I linked to?